# FCM Notification recieved but onclick notification current activity resume when app is background

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

**FCM** Notification recieved successfully first time click app launch and goto notification details activity. But when app go to background and notification recived and click on notification current activity `onResume()` method call. click not send data to launch activity and `onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage)` also not call